# How to set the default remote used by the git submodule init command?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm restructuring one of my git-repositories. So I cloned it locally to have a copy in case I mess up. Because of that, the origin now points to a folder on my local machine. When I now try to initialize the submodules (which are referenced by a relative URL), git tries to get the subrepository from my local machine and fails.

The documentation for the `git submodule init` subcommand says

> [..] If the URL is relative, it will be resolved using the default remote [..]

Where can I find the setting for the default remote?

How can I set the default remote?

Found something about the default push settings. But I can't figure out whether this has any effect on the `git submodule init` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the url.

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.MYSUBMODULE.url <URL>
git submodule sync
git submodule init
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `git submodule add` subcommand reveals the answer:

> The default remote is the remote of the remote-tracking branch of the current branch. If no such remote-tracking branch exists or the HEAD is detached, "origin" is assumed to be the default remote. If the superproject doesn’t have a default remote configured the superproject is its own authoritative upstream and the current working directory is used instead.